# FormIO refresh token implementation

Tags: angular, formio

I am implementing a anglar based form builder and renderer application. It is supposed to have a JWT based authentication with refresh tokens as well. I was able to use the fetch plugin in formio to intercept the request and add my JWT token. However now I am stuck.

When the JWT expires, I need to intercept the 401 response and reauthenticate the user from the backend and generate a new JWT. With this new JWT, I need to fetch the API again and send the response.

Any suggestions on this are most welcome.

Comment: This is interesting but to broad to comment on, without knowing anything about the application parts (Formio Forms/Endpoints, App, Another Backend etc.). Best would be a small demo app in codesandbox or something...